# Increasing .toString() size on Buffer in NodeJS (base64)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, base64, buffer

I'm running into an issue where when I try to convert a buffer to a base64 string, I receive the error: `Error: toString failed`

I did some digging around and it seems as though the .toString() method has a limit for the size it can convert. Is there any way to increase this size?

```
if (pdfData!=""){
    var b = new Buffer(pdfData);
    var s = b.toString('base64');
    ret = {"success":true,"id":angData.id,"data":s}; // Set disposition and send it.
}
res.send(ret);
```

I'm trying to convert my buffer to base64 so that I can download it in AngularJS.